# Yang-Mills instanton

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, instantons

How can [instanton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton) solution to Yang-Mills theory with gauge group $SU(3)$ or $SU(N)$ be obtained? For $SU(2)$ it is explained in textbooks but what about more general color gauge groups?

EDIT: How does $A^\mu$ look like for SU(3) or SU(N). Wikipedia only gives for SU(2). It is given by for SU(2)

$$A^\mu_a = 2/g \frac{\eta^a_{\mu\nu}(x-z)}{(x-z)^2+\rho^2}$$

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPST_instanton#Generalization_and_embedding_in_other_theories) tells you how to do it.

Comment: @Qmechanic why did you put a book tag on this? I rather thought he is looking for a reference and that the answer will rather be found in a paper than in a textbook ...? Certainly the question will be killed now with this tag even though it has 5 upvotes and 2 stars which means that many people would be interested in seing an answer here :-/

Comment: @Dilaton: Please take a moment to read the tag description for 'book' tags and 'ref.-req.' tags. It is irrelevant that OP casually uses the word 'ref'. Also please don't use tags themselves as arguments for or against in any closure/re-open discussion. They are in principle innocent bystanders. If a question is good enough to stay open/be re-opened, it should be so, independently of what tags are currently used. Wrong tagging just makes it more difficult to find questions for everyone.

Comment: @Qmechanic every question having the book tag gets killed these days here. Putting this on a question is like dishing out the sentence of dead for the question. Even if you just retag such that the right people can find the question and leave it otherwise alone, others will kill it anyway even though a potential wise answerer could maybe outline the explanation of the physics question I can see in this post in a direct answer and hint to a reference (or book or what ever) just for further information and details... :-(

Comment: I think the upvotes are because people would genuinely like to hear about instantons themselves (as opposed to just be handed a list of references and links). On that note, @Raj, it would be good if you (or somebody else?) could reformulate your question to ask an _actual_ physics question (as opposed to just asking for references).

Comment: @Qmechanic I'll try a rewording which can despense with the book tag I think. If I am not mistaken (?) this seems not too difficult to me (?).

Comment: Sorry if posting like answer. I forgot to register. My question is: how does the potential $A^\mu$ look like if SU(3) or SU(N) is considered? Wikipedia only shows for SU(2).

Comment: Hi @Raj. If you would like to merge your two accounts, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 2):

TO have an instanton solution, you need to map the (euclideanized) "spacetime at infinity" to the group manifold. In the case of SU(2), both the spacetime at infinity and the group manifold are $S^3$ and instantons are characterized by the integers. I hope you understand that much, at least for SU(2).

If you're interested in 4d instantons, they are characterized by $H_3(M_G)$ where $M_G$ is the group manifold -- since the spacetime at infinity is $S^3$. So, for every (homologically distinct) non-contractible 3-cycle of the group manifold, you can find an instanton. As the [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPST_instanton#Generalization_and_embedding_in_other_theories) given by @twistor says, the gauge fields corresponding to directions on that 3-cycle will have the same profile as the SU(2) instanton and the other gauge fields will have a trivial configuration (of course, up to a gauge transformation). Essentially, you're seeking the possible embeddings of SU(2) inside your gauge group and then making instantons out of those SU(2) subgroups.

If you understand that, the generalization to arbitrary number of dimensions should be straightforward.

Comment: Is SU(2) embeddable into SU(N), $N\geq 3$?

Comment: Yes. If you know some group theory, the Dynkin diagram of SU(2) is a single "dot" and for any SU(N) is a bunch of "dots" with some lines between them. The way I see it, roughly, you could place the SU(2) dot at each of the sites of the Dynkin diagrams of any larger group. In fact, there might be multiple embeddings. Maybe someone could give a link dealing with this.

Comment: Should it not be characterized by the third homotopy group $\pi_3$ rather than the third homology group $H_3$?

Comment: @RubenVerresen: I think you might be right. Do you have a physical explanation for why the relevant objects are homotopies instead of homologies, when talking about instantons on various manifolds?

Comment: @Siva: The usual `physics-y' way of looking at: suppose you have your instanton such that the action coincides with the second Chern number $\int F \wedge F$, then at the boundary on infinity this equals $\int_{S^3} \omega$ where by Stokes $d\omega = F \wedge F$. This means $\omega$ is the Chern-Simons form $\omega = A\wedge d A + \frac{2}{3} A^3$. But since we demand our curvature to be zero at infinity, our connection must be purely gauge $A = g^{-1}dg$. So the connection is determined by this $g$ as a function of $S^3$, i.e. a map $S^3 \to G$. But that is by definition $\pi_3(G)$.

Comment: The above is however not really rigorous: it shows that (1) the integral of the Chern-Simons form at infinity is an integer (since it has to be equal to the second Chern number on (compactified) spacetime), and (2) that the connection at infinity is determined by a map $S^3 \to G$. Hence it is very suggestive that the integral of the Chern-Simons form is measuring the index of the map $S^3 \to G$, but the above doesn't prove it.

Comment: A more 'maths-y' way: the set of topologically distinct $G$-bundles on a manifold X is equivalent to the set of homotopically distinct maps $X \to BG$, denoted as $[X,BG]$ (this is the classification theorem for vector bundles, where $BG$ is the classifying space of $G$). So we see that the instanton numbers on a spacetime $S^4$ are classified by $[S^4,BG] = \pi_4(BG)$. It is then a general fact from mathematics that $\pi_4(BG) = \pi_3(G)$. `Physically' this last equation says that the second Chern number on spacetime (left) coincides with the flat Chern-Simons action at infinity (right).